# How to turn the number into hex again after using "tonumber"?

Tags: lua

I transformed the address "1D8A1467" into number using "tonumber(address, 16)" what returned "495588455", and then summed +37 to that number to reach 495588492 and now I want to turn that new number into hex again in order to get the result "1D8A148C", is there a "tohex" function?

Answer (score 1):

```
local hexStr = string.format("%X", 495588492)
```

Please read the Lua manual!

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-string.format

For formatting options refer to

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: It worked using:
local newAdress = string.format("%x", adressNum * 16)

Comment: @GLAPPsMobile you don't have to multiply the number times 16 in order to convert it to a hexadecimal string